# Convexity of $11$-dimensional function without Hessian

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am working on a function with $11$ input parameters and would like to know if the function is convex. I am aware of the general definition that the Hessian matrix of the function should be positive semidefinite. However, given the complexity of my function, it is problematic to (at least analytically) calculate the Hessian matrix.

So I am wondering if there is any way to get a feeling for the convexity of my function. Similar to the univariate case where the following can be checked:

$$
f:X \rightarrow R \\
\forall x_1,x_2\in X, \forall t \in [0,1] : f(t x_1+(1-t)x_2)\le tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2) 
$$

How should I extend this to an $11$-dimensional case? Or should I rather aim for a numerical approximation of my Hessian matrix?

Comment: There *may* be other ways, but that depends on your function. It's the infamous [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), again.

Comment: I am assuming you have an analytic expression for your function. Please port it. There are simple rules that can help you regardless the number of dimensions. https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf or https://docs.mosek.com/MOSEKModelingCookbook-letter.pdf

Comment: "Function" is very broad. Polynomial, at least? Take a look at [After almost 20 years, math problem falls](http://news.mit.edu/2011/convexity-0715).

Comment: Convexity is the exception not the rule. If you don't have any clear reason to believe it is convex, you should probably assume it is not, and look for a counterexample (i.e., a pair of points $x_1$, $x_2$ that violate the secant rule above).